# Why in the following image that segment has length $r_2 - r_1$?

Tags: geometry, physics

[image: Here]

The problem is about finding the electric field produced by a dipole at a very distant point from the charges, which means that being so far the three segments $r_1, r$ and $r_2$ look parallel (and so $\theta \simeq \theta'$). I'm having hard times figuring out why the segment has length $r_2 - r_1$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, if all three angles are "equal" then the distance between $P$ and $+$ must equal the distance between $P$ and $-$.  Thus the distance from $P$ to $-$ must be $r_1$.  The desired claim follows from that.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for your answer! I'm having trouble to persuade myself about what's claimed there cause if I open a compass from P to $+q$ and then rotate on the direction of $r_2$ I don't get the drawn segment. Sorry for being stupid...

Comment: Well, of course in real life $P$ is not infinitely far away.  Just write it all out. 
 $d(P,+)=L\sin(\theta_+)$ and $d(P,-)=L\sin \theta_-$, where $L$ is the height of $P$ above the line and $\theta_-=\theta '$.  Now use the fact that $\theta_+-\theta_-=\epsilon$ for some very small $\epsilon$.

Comment: @lulu: Is for you $L$ what in the image is called $r$?

Comment: No.  $L$ is what I said...the perpendicular distance from $P$ to the line.

Comment: But, really, my first argument is the cleanest.  If $P$ is very far away then the distance to $P$ doesn't really depend on your exact location.  If I am measuring my distance to the moon, it doesn't matter if I get up and walk across the room.  Thus, $d(P,+)=d(P,-)$.

Comment: @lulu, Yeah it's just that I need that to get an approximation for the potential, which is $$V_P = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}(\frac{r_2 - r_1}{r_1r_2})$$ so I need to expand $r_2 - r_1$ as $a\cos(\theta')\simeq a\cos(\theta)$

Comment: Well, I don't see how to do that without information regarding $r_2$, but perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: If I assume what I'm asking as true, I can write down that:
$$r_2 - r_1 \simeq a\cos(\theta)$$
$$r_2  \simeq r + \frac{a}{2}\cos(\theta)$$
$$r_1  \simeq r - \frac{a}{2}\cos(\theta)$$

This would give me that $$r_1r_2 \simeq r^2 - \frac{a^2}{4}\cos^2(\theta) \simeq r^2$$

And therefore

$$V_P = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{a\cos(\theta)}{r^2}$$

Comment: That would only be true if the small triangle is a right triangle, but that assumption isn't stated anywhere.

Comment: @lulu: You're completely right! But still assuming that brings the correct result. See $(6.11)$ in this: http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_06.html

And I blindly trust Feynman.

Comment: Well, it's frustrating to try to guess what assumptions someone is making. Perhaps the original context makes that clear.

Comment: @lulu You can't imagine how it is for me to have to study something without understanding it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the figure I'd read this as follows: $r_1$ is the distance between $P$ and $\oplus$. $r_2$ is the distance between $P$ and $\ominus$. The line from $\oplus$ going up and right is either a line perpendicular to the "parallel" direction of the the black lines, or a big circle of radius $r_1$. At large distance the difference between these two becomes negligible. That line meets the line to $\ominus$ and splits it into two parts: one of length $r_1$ because that's how that split point is chosen, and one of length $r_2-r_1$ because that's what remains of the total length of $r_2$.